# Getting [ object object ] response when trying to fetch data from my api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to post my login information to api , Then store the userdata in localstorage of browser and this is my code

```
const Login = (e) => {
            // eslint-disable-next-line
        // const [user,setUser]=useContext(UserContext);
        const log = () => {
            const requestOptions = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 
                    'accept':'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    username: document.getElementById('username').value,
                    password: document.getElementById('password').value
                })
            };
            fetch('/api/bookdetails/login/', requestOptions)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(response => {
                    localStorage.setItem(response);
                    console.log(response);
                });
                window.location.href='/'
                
        }
        return (
            <div id="focus_form">

                <div className="section" id="login_section">
                    {/* <button onClick='form_out("login_section")' id='close' >X</button> */}
                    <h1 align='center'>Login</h1><br />
                    <center>
                        <p id='error'></p>
                        <form id='login_form' >
                            <input type='text' id='username' name='username' placeholder='usermame' autoComplete="off"
                                required /><br />
                            <input type='password' id='password' name='password' placeholder="password" required /><br />
                            <center>
                                <input type='button' onClick={log} value='LogIn'/><br />
                                <p>If you are new here</p>

                                <input type='button' name='signin' id='signin' value="SignIn" />
                            </center>
                        </form>
                    </center>
                </div >
            </div>
        )
    }
    export default Login;
```

When sending the same 'POST' request from postman i am getting the response is this which i want

```
{
    "user": "exist",
    "password": "valid",
    "userdetails": {
        "user_name": "xyz123",
        "full_name": "Whatever Daniel",
        "user_email": "dani@gmail.com",
        "college_name": "IISC",
        "city": "Bangalore",
        "country": "India"
    }
}
```

When I am sending the request from my application and the response stored in my localstorage is this

```
[object object]
```

**Can someone help me with this ??**

Comment: change your `console.log(YourResponseObject)` to `console.log({ YourResponseObject })` and see magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stringify your `data` then set it to `localStorage`

localStorage doesn't accept object. so convert it to string

```js
localStorage.setItem(data,JSON.stringify(data))
```

For retrieving data from localStorage

```js
const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(data))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `JSON.stringify()` before storing data it to `localStorage`.

To store data

```
localStorage.setItem("your_key_name", JSON.stringify(YOUR_JSON_DATA));
```

To retrieve

```
const myLocalData = localStorage.getItem("your_key_name"); // The returned data would be in string form, convert it to JSON.

const sanitizedData = JSON.parse(myLocalData);
```